# Doubts pandas filtering data row by row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How can I solve this issue related on pandas? I've a dataframe of the following approach:

| datetime64ns | type(int) | datetime64ns(analysis) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-02T10:02:05 | 4 |  |
| 2019-02-02T10:02:01 | 3 |  |
| 2019-02-02T10:02:02 | 4 | 2019-02-02T10:02:02 |
| 2019-02-02T10:02:04 | 3 | 2019-02-02T10:02:04 |

The goal is to do the following issue:

```
# psuedocode
for all the rows:
  if datetime(analysis) exists and type=4:
      insert in the a new row column type4=1
  
  elseif datetime(analysis) exists and type=2:
      insert in the a new row column type2=1
```

the idea to develop it is in order to make a group by count value. I'm sure that is possible because I manage to develop it in the past but I lost my .py file. Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1):

Need this?

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['type(int)'].mask(
    df['datetime64ns(analysis)'].isna()).astype('Int64')).add_prefix('type')], 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
          datetime64ns  type(int) datetime64ns(analysis)  type3  type4
0  2019-02-02T10:02:05          4                    NaN      0      0
1  2019-02-02T10:02:01          3                    NaN      0      0
2  2019-02-02T10:02:02          4    2019-02-02T10:02:02      0      1
3  2019-02-02T10:02:04          3    2019-02-02T10:02:04      1      0
```